# adding successive four / n numbers in large matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, large-data

I have very large dataset with dimension of `60K x 4 K`. I am trying add every four values in succession in every row column wise. The following is smaller example dataset.

```
    set.seed(123)
    mat <- matrix (sample(0:1, 48, replace = TRUE), 4)

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1     1     0     0
[2,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     0     0     0
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     0     0     0
[4,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0     0     0     0
```

Here is what I am trying to perform:

```
mat[1,1] + mat[1,2] + mat[1,3] + mat[1,4] = 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
```

i.e. add every four values and output.

```
mat[1,5] + mat[1,6] + mat[1,7] + mat[1,8] = 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 2
```

Keep going to end of matrix (here to 12).

```
mat[1,9] + mat[1,10] + mat[1,11] + mat[1,12]
```

Once first row is done apply the same to second row, like:

```
mat[2,1] + mat[2,2] + mat[2,3] + mat[2,4] 
mat[2,5] + mat[2,6] + mat[2,7] + mat[2,8]
mat[2,9] + mat[2,10] + mat[2,11] + mat[2,12]
```

The result will be `nrow x (ncol)/4` matrix.

The expected result will look like:

```
          col1-col4      col5-8   col9-12
row1        3              2        2
row2        2              2        1
row3        2              3        0
row4        3              4        0
```

Similarly for row 3 to number of rows in the matrix. How can I efficiently loop this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While Matthew's answer is really cool (+1, btw), you can get a much (~100x) faster solution if you avoid `apply` and use the `*Sums` functions (in this case `colSums`), and a bit of vector manipulation trickery:

```
funSums <- function(mat) {
  t.mat <- t(mat)                                    # rows become columns
  dim(t.mat) <- c(4, length(t.mat) / 4)              # wrap columns every four items (this is what we want to sum)
  t(matrix(colSums(t.mat), nrow=ncol(mat) / 4))      # sum our new 4 element columns, and reconstruct desired output format
}
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 48, replace = TRUE), 4)
funSums(mat)
```

Produces desired output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    2
[2,]    2    2    1
[3,]    2    3    0
[4,]    3    4    0
```

Now, let's make something the real size and compare against the other options:

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 6e5, replace = TRUE), 4)

funApply <- function(mat) {   # Matthew's Solution
  apply(array(mat, dim=c(4, 4, ncol(mat) / 4)), MARGIN=c(1,3), FUN=sum)
}
funRcpp <- function(mat) {    # David's Solution
  roll_sum(mat, 4, by.column = F)[, seq_len(ncol(mat) - 4 + 1)%%4 == 1]
}
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(times=10,
  funSums(mat),
  funApply(mat),
  funRcpp(mat)
)
```

Produces:

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr        min         lq     median       uq       max neval
  funSums(mat)   4.035823   4.079707   5.256517   7.5359  42.06529    10
 funApply(mat) 379.124825 399.060015 430.899162 455.7755 471.35960    10
  funRcpp(mat)  18.481184  20.364885  38.595383 106.0277 132.93382    10
```

And to check:

```
all.equal(funSums(mat), funApply(mat))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(funSums(mat), funRcpp(mat))
# [1] TRUE
```

The key point is that the `*Sums` functions are fully "vectorized", in as much as all the calculations happen in C.  `apply` still needs to do a bunch of not strictly vectorized (in the primitive C function way) stuff in R, and is slower (but far more flexible).

Specific to this problem, it might be possible to make it 2-3x faster as about half the time is spent on the transpositions, which are only necessary so that the `dim` changes do what I need for `colSums` to work.

Answer (score 8):

Dividing the matrix up into a 3D array is one way:

```
apply(array(mat, dim=c(4, 4, 3)), MARGIN=c(1,3), FUN=sum)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    1
# [3,]    2    3    0
# [4,]    3    4    0
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach using the `RcppRoll` package

```
library(RcppRoll) # Uses C++/Rcpp
n <- 4 # The summing range
roll_sum(mat, n, by.column = F)[, seq_len(ncol(mat) - n + 1) %% n == 1]

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    3    2    2
## [2,]    2    2    1
## [3,]    2    3    0
#3 [4,]    3    4    0
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the slowest of all:

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix (sample(0:1, 48, replace = TRUE), 4)
mat

output <- sapply(seq(4,ncol(mat),4), function(i) { apply(mat,1,function(j){
      sum(j[c(i-3, i-2, i-1, i)], na.rm=TRUE)
})})

output

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    2
[2,]    2    2    1
[3,]    2    3    0
[4,]    3    4    0
```

Maybe nested `for-loops` would be slower, but this answer is pretty close to being nested `for-loops`.